# Overwrite values in multiple columns at once based on condition of values in multiple columns, using indexing and broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

Here what I'm trying to do with a simple example,

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
npArray = np.random.randint(1, 8, (5, 5))
```

Gives this array,

```
[[5 6 1 4 4]
 [4 2 4 6 3]
 [5 7 1 1 5]
 [3 2 7 7 1]
 [2 6 2 6 1]]
```

I'm trying to get the following array with the last two columns modified to 9 for values >= 5 in the first two columns:

```
[[5 6 1 9 9]
 [4 2 4 6 3]
 [5 7 1 9 9]
 [3 2 7 7 1]
 [2 6 2 6 9]]
```

In code, I tried something like that:

```
npArray[npArray[:, :2] >= 5, :-2] = 9
```

Which gives the error:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 2-dimensional, but 3 were indexed
```

The broadcasting doesn't seems to work (is it be possible to make it works by adding a None/np.newaxis somewhere?), and I'm unable to figure it out.

Comment: try `npArray[:, :-2][npArray[:, :2] >= 5] = 9`

Comment: @hpaulj, this works! From my understanding, it is slower to do `npArray[:,:2][:2,:]` than `npArray[:2,:2]`. Is there a way to have the broadcasting done in the first pair of brackets?

Comment: @hpaulj It should be `npArray[:, -2:]` instead of `npArray[:, :-2]` for the first brackets.

Comment: The problem is indexing with a 2d boolean.  Separating out the slice makes the boolean match in shape.  Compared to the boolean indexing the slice won't take much time.

Comment: Compare `I,J = np.where(npArray[:, :2] >= 5)`.  The `J` values will be 0 or 1, the 2 sliced columns.  `J+3` would point to the last 2 columns.  So `npArray[I,J+3]=9` might work.  I don't know if it's any faster.

Comment: @hpaulj, This works also. But it is two time slower than `npArray[:, -2:][npArray[:, :2] >= 5] = 9`. I tested it for different array sizes. I'm still looking to make it works with broadcasting inside the first bracket.

Comment: Boolean arrays don't `broadcast` when indexing.  And as the `I,J` demonstrates, the mask identifies columns 0 and 1, but you want to modify 3 and 4.  `broadcasting` doesn't help.  An alternative is to create a (5,5) mask, but I suspect in the long run that's more work.

Comment: @hpaulj So something like this `A[np.arange(A.shape[0])[:,None],B]`, couldn't be applied to my case?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) like this:

```py
npArray[:, -2:] = np.where(npArray[:, :2] >= 5, 9, npArray[:, -2:])
print(npArray)
```

```
[[5 6 1 9 9]
 [4 2 4 6 3]
 [5 7 1 9 9]
 [3 2 7 7 1]
 [2 6 2 6 9]]
```

Comment: @anurag, What do you mean? It seems to provide the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1017]: arr = np.random.randint(0,9,(5,5))
In [1018]: arr
Out[1018]: 
array([[6, 0, 5, 3, 4],
       [6, 0, 4, 4, 8],
       [2, 3, 8, 7, 7],
       [6, 3, 6, 8, 8],
       [6, 4, 2, 4, 4]])
```

The boolean mask:

```
In [1019]: mask = arr[:,:2]>3
In [1020]: mask
Out[1020]: 
array([[ True, False],
       [ True, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True, False],
       [ True,  True]])
```

And the coordinates:

```
In [1021]: I,J=np.where(mask)    # np.nonzero
In [1022]: I,J
Out[1022]: (array([0, 1, 3, 4, 4]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1]))
```

The columns we want to change

```
In [1023]: arr[:,-2:]
Out[1023]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [4, 8],
       [7, 7],
       [8, 8],
       [4, 4]])
```

My first suggestion - slice first and then mask.  Slicing is a view, relatively fast, and more importantly, works.

```
In [1024]: arr[:,-2:][mask]=9
In [1025]: arr
Out[1025]: 
array([[6, 0, 5, 9, 4],
       [6, 0, 4, 9, 8],
       [2, 3, 8, 7, 7],
       [6, 3, 6, 9, 8],
       [6, 4, 2, 9, 9]])
```

The alternative of modifying the `J` index

```
In [1026]: arr[I,J+3]
Out[1026]: array([9, 9, 9, 9, 9])
```

The slicing approach is faster

```
In [1027]: timeit arr[:,-2:][mask]
1.42 µs ± 10.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [1028]: timeit arr[I,J+3]
5.98 µs ± 11.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The `where` step in the other answer:

```
In [1029]: np.where(mask, 9, arr[:,-2:])
Out[1029]: 
array([[9, 4],
       [9, 8],
       [7, 7],
       [9, 8],
       [9, 9]])
```